# Serialization of compiled Enum java

Tags: java, serialization, enums, jackson

I have an enum that's taken from a compiled library I imported into my project. When an object containing this enum is sent as an api response it contains the enum constant, like:

```
"attestation": "DIRECT"
```

I would like it as:

```
"attestation": "direct"
```

unfortunatly I can't change the enum class file and override the toString method or do anything similar.

So I've written a custom serializer for it:

```
public class AttestationConveyancePreferenceSerializer extends StdSerializer<AttestationConveyancePreference> {

    public AttestationConveyancePreferenceSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AttestationConveyancePreferenceSerializer(Class<AttestationConveyancePreference> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(AttestationConveyancePreference acp, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("attestation");
        jsonGenerator.writeString(acp.getValue());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

but now in the response I get:

```
    "attestation": {
      "attestation": "direct"
    },
```

is there a way to flatten the object?

Comment: What happens if you trim the body of the `serialize` method to just `jsonGenerator.writeString(acp.getValue());`?

Comment: You want this why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the value directly without creating an object:

```
    @Override
    public void serialize(AttestationConveyancePreference acp, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(acp.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `@JsonUnwrapped` to get a flatten object. Here you can find some examble https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonunwrapped.htm